# Fill FrameLayout with fixed footer

Tags: android, footer, android-framelayout

In a FrameLayout I add a WebView dynamically for save the content when rotate the screen, This is not the case, The case is that below of FrameLayout I want to put a fixed footer. The next code places the footer, but the FrameLayout it doesn't fill the screen.

I want to know your suggestions and advices or if there is some tip/example for achieving this. Thanks for your help!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_no_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_no_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_no_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_no_margin"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:background="@color/layout_black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|top" >
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/layout_black"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconAltara"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconFacebook"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconInstagram"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/instagram" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Framelayout's height as "match_parent" and make it above footer. Which is like below.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:background="@color/layout_black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|top" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Enjoy it, no problem !